# OpenShift Pro - Live & Test Sites - Best Practice / Alternatives

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, openshift, war

I now have a Java webapp running on OpenShift Pro that is automatically 'pushed to' from my local Eclipse IDE via GitHub. All very nice.

This is the **Test Site**, the local version is the **Development Site**.

What I want to do now is complete the lifecycle by creating a **Live Site** on OpenShift Pro that is deployed from a war (not from a git push). I believe the term is Binary Deployment.

What is the best way to go about this?

Can it be automated to any degree?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of a binary deployment is here: [Binary input sources in OpenShift 3.2](https://blog.openshift.com/binary-input-sources-openshift-3-2/)

It's pretty straight forward and does exactly what I wanted. I now have a complete development, test & live lifecycle.:-)